# Is there a createdDate field on ContentDocumentLink?

Tags: apex, soql, contentdocumentlink

I try to query the newest ContentDocumentLink on a record.
My approach is pretty simple. I want ORDER BY CreatedDate and LIMIT 1.

```
ContentDocumentLink cdl = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :linkedEntityId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1]
```

However, I get an error that there is no such column CreatedDate on entity ContentDocumentLink:

> No such column 'CreatedDate' on entity 'ContentDocumentLink'. If you
> are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c'
> after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the
> describe call for the appropriate names.

My current workaround is to order by createddate of the ContentDocument. However this includes the risk of failing when a document is assigned to the record late.

**How can I get the latest ContentDocumentLink on my record?**

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think you will have to refer ContentModifiedDate on ContentDocument object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from Workbench, there is no `CreatedDate` on `ContentDocumentLink`

[image]

You can use `SystemModstamp` for sorting

[Difference between LastModifiedDate and SystemModstamp](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387261&type=1)

Comment: This type of information is also (usually) available if you search for "X object reference" in your search engine of choice. To wit, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

Comment: Sadly, for System Fields, the Object Reference on a per object basis is not helpful; these system fields are covered in [this doc ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/system_fields.htm) and I've found you have to do a describe to check on edge cases like `ContentDocumentLink`